# Ptron car charge adapter has 2 outputs, which one is safe for charging mobile?

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, power-electronics, battery-charging

Ptron car charge adapter has two output:- output 1: "3USB" and output 2:"1USB" But oneplus phone 20W charger has 5V and 4A output.

[image: it has output 1: "3USB" and output 2:"1USB"]
it has output 1: "3USB" and output 2:"1USB"

[image: Confused which USB to use ? I think Blue is 1USB , correct if I'm wrong]
Confused which color is which 1USB or 3USB?
My assumption Blue is 1USB,Red is 3USB but TypeC output is unclear., correct if I'm wrong

whether i should charge my phone with Ptron's "3USB"(stated in it) output? Or  "1USB"(stated in it) port?
but "1USB" states 9 or 12v output where as my phone charger gives 5v . will it damage my phone if charged for long duration ?

Below question is Optional:
After seeing these chargers, I had a question. Why some phone charger,have multiple wattage and single wattage output? Which is better in terms of efficiency? Even If there is no single Method of charging applicable for all type of batteries,which method comparatively reaches the end of calculated lifetime of batteries

[image: compare the different wattages]

One plus stated single wattage, does that mean irrespective of battery percentage constant voltage will be provided or internal ICs will take care of ratios?

Comment: this is so common a misconception, there's a very canonical and detailed answer explaining why your assumption is wrong.